# A {wrap}bootstrap navbar in Aurelia just isn't working right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, aurelia

I've identified my problem, I just can't seem to work out a way around it.  I got a theme from {wrap}bootstrap because I am nobody's graphic designer and started piecing it together in Aurelia, based on the Navigation skeletons.

My issue is the navbar.  Using the skeleton, routes are configured in app.js - fine, no problem - and then one uses

```
<require from="nav-bar.html"></require>
```

to yank the navbar into one's page.  This is deforming the CSS because, as F12 informs me, a new element is added as the nav-bar component's container in the emitted HTML.  In this case, it's

```
<nav-bar class="au-target" router.bind="router" au-target-id="1">
<!-- usual bootstrap navbar stuff -->
</nav-bar>
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: Your solution is a containerless view. Search the Aurelia documentation for the word `containerless`.

Comment: you're absolutely correcxt, @LStarky.  Please post this as an answer so I can give you a solution credit.

Comment: This solution is posted now. If you have any further difficulties don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: The thing is this shouldn't be causing an issue. We use this in our skeletons and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Aurelia's `@containerless` Decorator:**

To accomplish this you'll want to use Aurelia's `@containerless` decorator.  As far as I know you need to have a full component, not just an HTML view.  If you don't already also have a `nav-bar.js`, it's no big deal to create one.

**Example nav-bar.js:**

```
import {containerless} from 'aurelia-framework';

@containerless
export class NavBar {
}
```

**Usage:**

First, require your view `nav-bar` in the parent view, like this.  Be sure *not* to specify the `.html` since you want it to look for the viewmodel also:

```
<require from="nav-bar"></require>
```

Then, further down in your view in the correct location, use the element tag to include it.

```
<nav-bar></nav-bar>
```

**Alternate approach using `Compose` Element:**

I've never used this, but it might also be a good approach.  According to [this blog article](http://ilikekillnerds.com/2015/10/aurelia-dynamic-composition/) by Dwayne Charrington, you could also use the built-in Aurelia element `<compose>` to import a containerless view and/or a view without the viewmodel.  It doesn't explicitly say you can do both so I'm making an assumption that it would work.  Give it a shot and let me know if I need to update this answer post.

```
<compose view="nav-bar.html" containerless></compose>
```